Nintendo 2DS refuses to charge
So, I left my Nintendo 2DS in storage for about a month, and when I try and use it, it doesn't charge.
It worked fine before. Could it have something to do with the charger?

Is it in good shape? Can you send an image of your charger?

Also, is it a DS, 2DS, or 3DS? You said DS in your tag, 2DS in your title, and 3DS in your question.

I would recommend showing both the port that goes to the DS, and the port that goes into the wall, just in case. Also a close up on the port the charger goes into on the DS would be helpful.

I meant 2DS and the charger and console are both like- new.

2DS? Nice. I love those. Ok, so, a picture could help us figure out what could be happening with the charger. Better visuals, better answers.

@PenguRoxy You'd better return it to wherever you got it from then... Or trying to call in for a warranty repair (if you even have that where you are; in AU there's a six month guarentee). But as everyone else has stated, we need more information to be able to help you, such as more pictures (and as much as possible that's relevant) and any tests you've conducted.

@Aytimothy agreed!

You mention leaving the 2DS in storage for a month. If the 2DS was still powered on when left in storage, it's possible the battery has drained completely. In that case, the battery will refuse to charge. This is a security feature of Lithium-Ion batteries to prevent fires, which is extremely dangerous when Lithium is involved. You can read more about the risks of charging a once-depleted battery here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164103/if-li-ion-battery-is-deeply-discharged-is-it-harmful-for-it-to-remain-in-this-s

@PenguRoxy Does the 2DS turn on and show it's battery level? It is possible that the battery hasn't drained much during the month, which has happened to me before. If it doesn't turn on, then maybe the battery is low enough that the system's charging lights won't turn on, so maybe leaving it plugged in for a bit will get it charging. I would HIGHLY recommend keeping Nolonar's comment in mind for future references, cause... yikes!

No. I've had it for about 5 years though and had no issues with it since then.
